# Unable to run docker or service docker

Tags: docker

I have installed the Docker Toolbox from here https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox on my computer(which has OSX). If I try running something like:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it --rm b.gcr.io/tensorflow-udacity/assignments:0.5.0
```

I am getting this issue:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

After looking here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17645 I tried using

```
sudo service docker start
```

However, I am getting this message:

```
sudo: service: command not found
```

So how can I run docker on my computer?

Comment: Did you check that your PATH has been updated with Docker ? I guess you can't run service docker start because Docker files aren't in your PATH.

Comment: Yes, PATH has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new 'Docker Shell' that also got installed and stuff should automatically be on your path.